# Action Creator not awaiting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm using placeholder json api in my application to fetch some posts ans their users. However the users had duplicated ID's and those were being fetched multiple times.. So i tried the following code to fetch only unique ids.. However as i console logged getState().posts for debugging it is showing an empty array because the api is being called later.

What i dont understand is why isnt 'await' working..

Also, fetchUser is never getting called i can't understand why..

i am new to redux and sorry if this is a dumb question
Here's my code

```
import _ from 'lodash' ;

export const fetchEvery = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
console.log("Before") ;
await dispatch(fetchData()) ;
console.log("After" , getState()) ;
const ids = _.uniq(_.map(getState().posts, 'userId')) ;
console.log(ids) ;
ids.forEach( id => dispatch(fetchUser(id))) ;
} ;

export const fetchData = () => dispatch => {
    let resp = {} ;

    fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
    .then( res => {
            if ( res.ok )
              return res.json() ;
            else 
              throw Error(res.statusText)
          } )
    .then( res => {
            console.log(res) ;
            resp = res ;
            dispatch( {
                    type : 'FETCH_DATA' ,
                    payload : resp  
                }) ;
                    } )
    .catch( err => console.log(err) ) ;

} ;

export const fetchUser = (id) => (dispatch) => {
fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + id )
.then( res => {
            if ( res.ok )
              return res.json() ;
            else 
              throw Error(res.statusText)
          } )
    .then( res => {
            console.log(res) ;
            dispatch( {
                    type : 'FETCH_USER' ,
                    payload : res  
                }) ;
                    } )
    .catch( err => console.log(err) ) ;

} ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fetch methods `return` the `fetch`. Currently they're not returning anything - so no promises - thus your `await` at the top level is resolving immediately as there is no promise to `wait` for.